# How to write a matcher for Integer.class

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I'm trying to write a unit test and I can't seem to figure out how to write a Mockito matcher for Integer.class.

I'm trying to test the following method:

```
public List<Integer> getAllParticipatingChallengesByTeamId(int teamId) {
        List<Integer> challengeIds = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        MapSqlParameterSource args = new MapSqlParameterSource();

        args.addValue("teamId", teamId);
        try {
            challengeIds = jdbcTemplate.queryForList(SQL_STRING, args, Integer.class);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            challengeIds = null;
        }

        return challengeIds;
    }
```

by stubbing my mocked jdbcTemplate to return a value using matchers like this:

```
    when(mockJdbc.queryForList(anyString(), any(SqlParameterSource.class), any(Integer.class)).thenReturn(integerList);
```

But of course that matches any Integer, not any class! I tried Class.class, and such, but I couldn't seem to figure it out online or through my own means.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `eq(Integer.class)` which is the equality matcher in Mockito